# Date at 00:00 is not new days date

Tags: javascript

I want to have new days date at a task running at 00:00. My code uses the date of the past day.

Example: the code runs at 2019-04-12 00:00 but returns 2019-04-11 00:00.

```
 var nowtime = new Date();
 var nowDate = nowtime.toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

Even if i run it at 00:01 it uses the date from yesterday. May i ask for some advice.

Comment: you have to account for timezones

Comment: `toISOString` returns a UTC time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with including my timezone.

```
var nowDate = nowtime.toLocaleDateString('DE-DE',{year:'numeric',month:"2-digit", day:"2-digit"});
```